# What's the correct way to revert Mysql 5.7 strict mode back to how it was in 5.6?

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I've upgraded our server to Ubuntu 16 which includes Mysql 5.7 and, by default, Strict Mode is enabled (although there is no entry for it in any of the configuration files).

We're having issues importing databases that were in production under mysql 5.6 and earlier, and it's because of the strict mode. By default, here is what's enabled:

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

How can I configure mysql 5.7 to work exactly as it did in 5.6 or so that databases from 5.6 are compatible with 5.7?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34426883/534883 event though it is for OSX, it worked for my on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 36):

To disable strict SQL mode, SSH in to your server as `root` and create this file:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf
```

Open the file and enter these two lines:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart MySQL with this command:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

This change disables two SQL mode settings, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, that were added in MySQL 5.7 and cause problems for some older applications.

#### Confirming Strict SQL Mode Is Disabled

You can confirm strict SQL mode is disabled by running this command as `root`:

```
 sudo mysql -i -BN -e 'SELECT @@sql_mode' | grep -E 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY|STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
```

If strict mode is disabled, you won't see any output from that command.

If disabling strict mode causes any problems for you, you can enable it again by deleting that file and restarting MySQL again.

Source: [How to Disable Strict SQL Mode in MySQL 5.7](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-disable-strict-mode-in-mysql-5-7.html)

Comment: This is a correct answer, and this should have been marked as accepted.

Comment: Why does running the command mysql command returns: 
`mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf at line 1!`
?

Comment: @AbhishekSaini, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020297/mysql-my-cnf-file-found-option-without-preceding-group) and [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/471372/etc-my-cnf-what-i-am-missing).

Comment: This is a answer. Please refer this as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set `sql_mode` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` without `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`.

Add under `[mysqld]`:

```
sql_mode = NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```